# How can I adjust the width of a span element to match the width of the text?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

[image]

I have a span like that in the image. The span content can be wrapped into two line if the text doesn't fit in one line. The image with the plant should be placed exactly next to the span, like this.

[image]

`width:fit-content` should be what I want, but it doesn't work as I expected, if I set `witdh:min-content` than it always wrapped into two line, what I also don't want.

Any idea how can I handle this? This is one menu item, next to this item there are many more

This is how one menu-item looks like

```
<div class="flex w-max">
    <span class="py-3 pl-4 hover:bg-black/20 text-start flex items-end ">
      {{__('navbar.events')}}
    </span>
    <img class="min-w-10 w-10" src="{{asset('assets/images/vertical_divider.jpg')}}">
</div>
```

Comment: you cannot ....